# What was the name of the wife of Elozor HaCohen?

Tags: women, midrash, kohen-priest, pentateuch-chumash

What was the name of the wife of Elozor HaCohen? (Assuming she was the sister of tzipporah and daughter of Yisro)

Comment: במדרש ילקוט ראובני מונה שמותיהן על פי הקבלה:

צפורה פנינה קציעה ימימה נעמה זריעה וזליחה.

Comment: Why would you so assume?

Comment: What's with these wierd spellings "Elozor"?

Comment: @HachamGabriel: Alef-segol = E. Lamed-sh'va-nach = l. Ayin-kamatz = o. Zayin = z. Kamatz = o. Resh = r.

Comment: @msh210 why is Kamatz an "o"?

Comment: @HachamGabriel, I guess because it sounds pretty much like the vowel in (American) "cot", or, depending on one's pronunciation of Hebrew, pretty much like the first vowel in "color". Either way, "o" is reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm going to get minuses for this, but I am almost positive that there is no source for her name.